Python subprocess.Popen command in loop, wait until finished
I have a problem very similar to this topic
I have a loop running multiple subprocess.Popen commands :
    for filename in filenames:
        completed_process = subprocess.Popen(
            f"snt_sim -yaml {filename}", shell=True, stdout=subprocess.DEVNULL
        )

I want to wait until all of the process are finished before continuing in the program, but I don't necessarily want to wait after each command. If possible, I would like to run them all, then wait for them to finish.
Is there a simple way of doing this ? The only solution I thought of was stocking every completed_process variable in a list, and after the for loop, call completed_process.communicate() for each in the list. But this solution doesn't seems very elegant.

You could use concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor, which offers you to wait for all futures before continuing (concurrent.futures.ALL_COMPLETED)

@MauriceMeyer Okay so it's a module implementing asynchronous programaming. I was looking for a way to do that using only the subprocess module, but thanks for your help !
